# What are good documentation on CGI?

Tags: cgi

I want to learn more about how CGI works internally. I am not looking for a library or documentation on how to use the library, but rather for documentation on how the server and the application will communicate, what data gets sent, in what order it gets sent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing is better than a rfc :)

[RFC3875](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875.txt)